# EF Core 6 add-migration is recreating table

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In my previous migration there already is a `migrationBuilder` for my entity and after some changes when I use `add-migration` the `migrationBuilder` is recreating the entity

Before

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AppDespesaExtraOrcamentaria",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Exercicio = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                CodigoReduzido = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                Conta = table.Column<long>(type: "bigint", nullable: false),
                Complemento = table.Column<short>(type: "smallint", nullable: false),
                Descricao = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(50)", nullable: true),
                FundoId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                FornecedorId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                FonteDeRecursoId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true),
                CodigoDeAplicacaoId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true),
                DestinacaoRecursoId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true),
                FonteDeRecursoSICONFIId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true),
                ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(40)", maxLength: 40, nullable: true),
                CreationTime = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
                CreatorId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: true),
                LastModificationTime = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: true),
                LastModifierId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: true),
                TenantId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AppDespesaExtraOrcamentaria", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AppDespesaExtraOrcamentaria_AppCodigoDeAplicacao_CodigoDeAplicacaoId",
                    column: x => x.CodigoDeAplicacaoId,
                    principalTable: "AppCodigoDeAplicacao",
                    principalColumn: "Id");
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AppDespesaExtraOrcamentaria_AppDestinacaoRecurso_DestinacaoRecursoId",
                    column: x => x.DestinacaoRecursoId,
                    principalTable: "AppDestinacaoRecurso",
                    principalColumn: "Id");
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AppDespesaExtraOrcamentaria_AppFonteDeRecurso_FonteDeRecursoId",
                    column: x => x.FonteDeRecursoId,
                    principalTable: "AppFonteDeRecurso",
                    principalColumn: "Id");
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AppDespesaExtraOrcamentaria_AppFonteDeRecursoSICONFI_FonteDeRecursoSICONFIId",
                    column: x => x.FonteDeRecursoSICONFIId,
                    principalTable: "AppFonteDeRecursoSICONFI",
                    principalColumn: "Id");
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AppDespesaExtraOrcamentaria_AppFornecedor_FornecedorId",
                    column: x => x.FornecedorId,
                    principalTable: "AppFornecedor",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AppDespesaExtraOrcamentaria_AppFundo_FundoId",
                    column: x => x.FundoId,
                    principalTable: "AppFundo",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });
migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_AppDespesaExtraOrcamentaria_TenantId_Conta",
            table: "AppDespesaExtraOrcamentaria",
            columns: new[] { "TenantId", "Conta" },
            unique: true,
            filter: "[TenantId] IS NOT NULL");
```

After

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AppDespesaExtraOrcamentaria",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Exercicio = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                CodigoReduzido = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                Conta = table.Column<long>(type: "bigint", nullable: false),
                Complemento = table.Column<short>(type: "smallint", nullable: false),
                Descricao = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(50)", nullable: true),
                FundoId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                FornecedorId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                FonteDeRecursoId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true),
                CodigoDeAplicacaoId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true),
                DestinacaoRecursoId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true),
                FonteDeRecursoSICONFIId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true),
                ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(40)", maxLength: 40, nullable: true),
                CreationTime = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
                CreatorId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: true),
                LastModificationTime = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: true),
                LastModifierId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: true),
                TenantId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_AppDespesaExtraOrcamentaria", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AppDespesaExtraOrcamentaria_AppCodigoDeAplicacao_CodigoDeAplicacaoId",
                    column: x => x.CodigoDeAplicacaoId,
                    principalTable: "AppCodigoDeAplicacao",
                    principalColumn: "Id");
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AppDespesaExtraOrcamentaria_AppDestinacaoRecurso_DestinacaoRecursoId",
                    column: x => x.DestinacaoRecursoId,
                    principalTable: "AppDestinacaoRecurso",
                    principalColumn: "Id");
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AppDespesaExtraOrcamentaria_AppFonteDeRecurso_FonteDeRecursoId",
                    column: x => x.FonteDeRecursoId,
                    principalTable: "AppFonteDeRecurso",
                    principalColumn: "Id");
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AppDespesaExtraOrcamentaria_AppFonteDeRecursoSICONFI_FonteDeRecursoSICONFIId",
                    column: x => x.FonteDeRecursoSICONFIId,
                    principalTable: "AppFonteDeRecursoSICONFI",
                    principalColumn: "Id");
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AppDespesaExtraOrcamentaria_AppFornecedor_FornecedorId",
                    column: x => x.FornecedorId,
                    principalTable: "AppFornecedor",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_AppDespesaExtraOrcamentaria_AppFundo_FundoId",
                    column: x => x.FundoId,
                    principalTable: "AppFundo",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });
migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_AppDespesaExtraOrcamentaria_TenantId_Conta_Complemento_Exercicio",
            table: "AppDespesaExtraOrcamentaria",
            columns: new[] { "TenantId", "Conta", "Complemento", "Exercicio" },
            unique: true,
            filter: "[TenantId] IS NOT NULL");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_AppDespesaExtraOrcamentaria_TenantId_Exercicio_CodigoReduzido",
            table: "AppDespesaExtraOrcamentaria",
            columns: new[] { "TenantId", "Exercicio", "CodigoReduzido" },
            unique: true,
            filter: "[TenantId] IS NOT NULL");
```

Comment: Migrations are created by comparing `DbContext.Model` with `DatabaseModelSnapshot` in your migration assembly, then creating a new replacement snapshot. Was the model snapshot preserved when you created your first migration?

Comment: And you can edit the generated migration code...